# Chain animations in UIVIEW inside of for loop

Tags: animation, core-animation, uilabel, sequence, uiviewanimation

I have some problems with animations. Here is what I am trying to do.
First I have a *for* loop where I make some animations of UILabels, for example

```
    label1.frame = CGRectMake(xBoard, 5, textWidth, term1Label.frame.size.height);
    xBoard = xBoard + textWidth;
    label1.textColor = term1Label.textColor;
    label1.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:textHeight];
    label1.textAlignment = term1Label.textAlignment;
    label1.text = label1String;
    label1.alpha = 0;
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [boardView addSubview:label1];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0*time
                          delay:timeDelay
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                           label1.alpha = 1;
                   } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             }
                 ];

    timeDelay = timeDelay + 2.0*time;
```

Some labels appear, some disappear, some change color. Everything is working fine until I make second loop. Then the first part of code just appear (the animations of changing color are still working but all labels from first loop are visible and do not animate. Second loop animates fine.

I was trying to replace the animations [UIView animateWithDuration:...] with CABasicAnimations and save them in one NSMutableArray with queue, but I am not successful. Probably my knowledge is too short yet. Any help is welcome. Thanks!!!

Comment: What is wrong with all the other "how do I nest/chain/make sequential/etc. animations?"? The same question has been asked many times with minor alternations. Try searching for these. Maybe you even see something in the "related" list to the right…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem. Here is a correctly working code

```
 - (void)performAnimations {
// Finish when there are no more animations to run

int i = animationNumber;
int tag = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
int animation = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1]intValue];
float animTime = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:2]floatValue];
//float animDelay = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:3]floatValue];
float animDelay = 0;
float parameter = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:4]floatValue];

UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc];
UIView *view = [UIView alloc];
if ([[self.view viewWithTag:tag] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
    label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
} else if ([[self.view viewWithTag:tag] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
    view = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
}

switch (animation) {
    case 1:
        [self colorizeLabelForAWhile:label withUIColor:[UIColor yellowColor] animated:YES withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self appear:label withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
        break;
    case 3:
        [self disappear:label withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
        break;
    case 4:
        [self moveView:view withOffset:parameter withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}

 -(void)animationDidFinished{
animationNumber = animationNumber + 1;
if (animationNumber == [[self animations] count]) {
    [animations removeAllObjects];
    return;
} else {
    [self performAnimations];
}
}


-(void)colorizeLabelForAWhile:(UILabel *)label withUIColor:(UIColor *)tempColor animated:(BOOL)animated withTime:(float)time withDelay:(float)delay{
UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
tempLabel.textColor = tempColor;
tempLabel.font = label.font;
tempLabel.alpha = 0;
tempLabel.textAlignment = label.textAlignment;
tempLabel.text = label.text;
tempLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[label.superview addSubview:tempLabel];
tempLabel.frame = label.frame;

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                              delay:delay
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             // Animate it
                             label.alpha = 0;
                             tempLabel.alpha = 1;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                                                   delay:0
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                              animations:^{
                                                  // Animate it back.
                                                  label.alpha = 1;
                                                  tempLabel.alpha = 0;
                                              } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                // Remove the tempLabel view when we are done.
                                                  [tempLabel removeFromSuperview];
                                                  if (finished) {
                                                      [self animationDidFinished];
                                                  }

                                              }];
                         }];

    } else {
        // Change it back at once and remove the tempLabel view.
        label.alpha = 1.0;
        [tempLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }
}


-(void)appear:(UILabel *)label withTime:(float)time withDelay:(float)delay{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                          delay:delay
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         label.alpha = 1.0;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Anim Appear %d",label.tag);
                         if (finished) {
                             [self animationDidFinished];
                         }
                     }];

 }

 -(void)disappear:(UILabel *)label withTime:(float)time withDelay:(float)delay{
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                      delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     label.alpha = 0.0;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Anim Disappear %d",label.tag);
                     [label removeFromSuperview];
                     if (finished) {
                         [self animationDidFinished];
                     }

                 }];

 }

 -(void)moveView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(float)offset withTime:(float)time withDelay:(float)delay{
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                      delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = view.frame;
                     frame.origin.y += offset;
                     view.frame = frame;
               } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                   if (finished) {
                       [self animationDidFinished];
                   }
               }
 ];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the middle of solving my problem. Doing my loops I am saving animation parameters in the table

```
         NSArray *animation1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber       numberWithInt:label1.tag], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f*time],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:timeDelay],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],nil];
                [animations addObject:animation1];
```

in the end of void I call [self performAnimations];

```
   - (void)performAnimations {
if ([[self animations] count] == 0) return;

for (int i=0; i<[[self animations] count]; i++) {

    int tag = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
    int animation = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1]intValue];
    float animTime = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:2]floatValue];
    float animDelay = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:3]floatValue];
    float parameter = [[[animations objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:4]floatValue];

    UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc];
    UIView *view = [UIView alloc];
    if ([[self.view viewWithTag:tag] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
    } else if ([[self.view viewWithTag:tag] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        view = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
    }

    switch (animation) {
        case 1:
            [PolyCalcsViewController colorizeLabelForAWhile:label withUIColor:[UIColor yellowColor] animated:YES withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
            break;
        case 2:
            [PolyCalcsViewController appear:label withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
            break;
        case 3:
            [PolyCalcsViewController disappear:label withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
            break;
        case 4:
            [PolyCalcsViewController moveView:view withOffset:parameter withTime:animTime withDelay:animDelay];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

[animations removeAllObjects];
```

}

```
  +(void)colorizeLabelForAWhile:(UILabel *)label withUIColor:(UIColor *)tempColor animated:(BOOL)animated withTime:(float)time withDelay:(float)delay{
UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
tempLabel.textColor = tempColor;
tempLabel.font = label.font;
tempLabel.alpha = 0;
tempLabel.textAlignment = label.textAlignment;
tempLabel.text = label.text;
tempLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[label.superview addSubview:tempLabel];
tempLabel.frame = label.frame;

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                              delay:delay
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             // Animate it
                             label.alpha = 0;
                             tempLabel.alpha = 1;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                                                   delay:0
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                              animations:^{
                                                  // Animate it back.
                                                  label.alpha = 1;
                                                  tempLabel.alpha = 0;
                                              } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                // Remove the tempLabel view when we are done.
                                                  [tempLabel removeFromSuperview];
                                              }];
                         }];

    } else {
        // Change it back at once and remove the tempLabel view.
        label.alpha = 1.0;
        [tempLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

}

```
   +(void)appear:(UILabel *)label withTime:(float)time withDelay:(float)delay{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                          delay:delay
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         label.alpha = 1.0;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Anim Appear %d",label.tag);
                     }];        
     }

    +(void)disappear:(UILabel *)label withTime:(float)time withDelay:(float)delay{
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                      delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     label.alpha = 0.0;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Anim Disappear %d",label.tag);
                     [label removeFromSuperview];
                 }];    
        }
```

The point is that program is not performing animations in sequence how it is in the table animations. I think I should give up of time delay and run the next animation when the previous one is finished. I could make a counter in the completion:(BOOL finished) block, but I do not know how because the function doesn't accept external variable. Any ideas how to detect the end of animation and control the table execution? Thanks.